# wxpython drag and drop one folder then another to add to list

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I am using the code below which creates a drag and drop window, to where I am dropping a folder onto to get a folder path. What I want is to be able to drop one folder, then drop another folder, which adds to the list, then maybe another which adds to the list, and so on. Currently If I drop another folder after the first one it only displays the first one in the window. How do I get it to display the new ones being added, and add them to the list?

```
    def queue(self, event):
        self.Show()
        dt1 = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel1, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(42, 120), size=(500, 405))
        self.tc_files.SetDropTarget(dt1)

    def notify(self, indir):
        """Update file in testcontrol after drag and drop"""
        self.tc_files.SetValue(indir[0])

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        self.window.notify(filenames)
```

Comment: just modify the notify function to set the string to all of them rather than just the first one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoranBeasley commented, you need to use the indir list to set the string that you display:

```
self.tc_files.SetValue(",".join(indir))
```

should do it.